# Where is the bin directory which includes gdb in the Eclipse folder hierarchy?

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, ide

I just installed (just an unzip and copy of the files) Eclipse from

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers (includes Incubating components)

I can not find the bin directory containing gdb.

Comment: Eclipse is just an IDE. It can be used with dozens or hundreds of languages. If you want [GDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GDB), then install that package too. It's in package `gdb` on Ubuntu, probably other distributions use similar names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow below steps:

> - Install Eclipse
> - Install PDE
> - Install CDT
>
>   -done-